# call a function every time a route is updated vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, intercom

I have integrated intercom in my app and I need to call `window.Intercom('update');` every-time my url changes.

I know I could add it on `mounted()` but I rather not modify all my component and do it directly using the [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html). (Mainly to avoid to have the same code in 10 different places.

At the moment I have:

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  eventHub.$off(); // I use this for an other things, here is not important
  console.log(window.location.href ) // this prints the previous url
  window.Intercom('update'); // which means that this also uses the previous url
})
```

This runs `intercom('update')` before changing the url, while I need to run it after the url changes.

Is there a hook which runs just when the url has changed? 
How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could try [watching the `$route` object](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) in your `Vue` instance.

Comment: @thanksd I'm saying that it hasn't yet changed because on line 3 the `console.log(window.location.href )` print the previous url. e.g. from home I click on /about, it prints home, then I click on /team it prints /about etc

Comment: @Phil you mean adding a watcher in my base component? this could work.. I just usually try to avoid watchers, but here it might make sense

Comment: why not just add a mounted hook to App.vue. All the other components are children to the App.vue

Comment: Yeah, base component or Vue instance (eg `new Vue(...)`)

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior because I would have the same code in 7 different places and I would have to remember to add it every-time I make a new component/page, not super efficient

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior Vue components inherit nothing from their parents

Comment: @Phil I mean each time you navigate to a component, the parent component is also mounted.

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior no it isn't

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior @Phil the `watch` worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Phil, watching $route in the vue instance seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @Phil feel free to add it as a correct answer. It might help others and it will be more visible than these comments. Thank You.

Comment: ok great! but am sure the mounted hook on the App.vue will also work because I have been using it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wasn't sure this would work as what you already have seems like it should be fine but here goes...

Try [watching the `$route` object](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) for changes

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  watch: {
    '$route': function(to, from) {
      Intercom('update')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: the order of the params should `to, from`, otherwise exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jonas they're just names but you're right, the arguments should be reversed. Will fix

Comment: for me, watching` '$route'` did not detect the changes, but `$route` did. I meant i had to remove the quotes.

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder shouldn't make any difference at all

Answer (score 2):

I just came up with another solution beyond Phil's, you could also use [Global Mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin). It merges its methods or lifecycle hooks into every component.

```
Vue.mixin({
  mounted() {
    // do what you need
  }
})
```

Comment: I would advise against this solution. This may work if you're using a simple implementation with one component per route, however with this method the mounted() event will get attached to every component, so if you have one or many subcomponents in a route the event will run once for each of them. This will likely result in unintended and uncontrollable behavior in your application.

Answer (score -1):

```
created() {
    this.$watch(
      () => this.$route.params,
      () => /*Your Function*/
    );
  },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).